# Getting count of products before filters are applied

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I have an array of products:

```
[
  {
    "title": "ring 1",
    "tags": [
      "gemstone__morganite",
      "material__rose-gold",
      "ring-type__cocktail-rings",
      "ring-type__engagement-rings"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "ring 2",
    "tags": [
      "material__platinum",
      "ring-type__cocktail-rings",
      "ring-type__engagement-rings"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "ring 3",
    "tags": [
      "gemstone__diamond",
      "material__rose-gold",
      "ring-type__engagement-rings",
      "ring-type__etched-rings"
    ]
  }
]
```

I am filtering the products using an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "gemstone": [],
  "material": [
    "material__platinum",
    "material__rose-gold"
  ],
  "ring-type": [
    "ring-type__cocktail-rings",
    "ring-type__etched-rings"
  ]
}
```

My filters are grouped by the key and built so they look like this:

[image: Imgur]

I then have a count next to each filter to indicate how many of each product will show when the filter is clicked.

This works fine on first load but after filters are applied the numbers needs to update accordingly.

The filters work so that any within the same group use 'or' logic. So, if 'material_platimun' and 'material__rose-gold' were selected it would should all products that have either one of those tags.

If you were to then select a tag from another group it uses 'and' logic. So, if 'material_platimun', 'material__rose-gold', 'ring-type__cocktail-rings' and 'ring-type__etched-rings' it would show the products above. (e.g all products with 'material_platimun' OR 'material__rose-gold' AND 'ring-type__cocktail-rings' OR 'ring-type__etched-rings')

I am am filtering the products using a function that looks like this:

```
if (Object.entries(filters).length !== 0 && filters.constructor === Object) {
   for (let key in filters) {
        if (Array.isArray(filters[key]) && filters[key].length) {
            result = result.filter(object => filters[key].some(r => object.tags.includes(r)));
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine but I can't build the expected numbers of products from the result as it is a step too late. I need to know how many products will show before the products are filtered.

I am currently building the count based off what tags are selected like so:

```
const tags = [];
const count = {};

Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    val.tags.forEach(el => {
       tags.push(el);
    });
})

tags.forEach(i => {
    count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
});

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(count)) {
    const markup = `
        <span>\u00A0(${value})</span>
    `;

    const el = tmpl.querySelector('[data-tag-handle=' + key + '] label');

    el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
}
```

Does anyone know how I could go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to make is called faceted search. A custom implementation may worth it but probably you better consider specialised database management systems. I would suggest looking at Apache Solr or Elastic Search. Both of them have this feature.

Comment: Do you have any idea as to how I could solve this with a custom implementation? I don't think any of the solutions you suggested are applicable in my situation.

Comment: I would try to go over the data set and count number of matches for every potential filter in your filter control. It could be quite an expensive operation if your dataset is large, but then you are not going to select the data you are just counting.